# ¿Cómo asignar las etiquetas en geom_pie_glyph?

Tags: r, ggplot

Estoy tratando de analizar el porcentaje de presencia de cada microorganismo a lo largo del tiempo. Para ello, he creado un gráfico circular que muestra esta distribución a lo largo del tiempo. Sin embargo, estoy teniendo dificultades para colocar las etiquetas correspondientes a los porcentajes de cada grupo en el lugar adecuado del gráfico.

Adjunto la base de datos con la que estoy trabajando.

```
    dput(Evolucion_ais.ggplot)
    structure(list(tiempos = c("12M", "12M", "12M", "12M", "12M", 
    "12M", "12Mpre", "12Mpre", "12Mpre", "12Mpre", "12Mpre", "12Mpre", 
    "15Mpre", "15Mpre", "15Mpre", "15Mpre", "15Mpre", "15Mpre", "18Mpre", 
    "18Mpre", "18Mpre", "18Mpre", "18Mpre", "18Mpre", "18Mpre", "21Mpre", 
    "21Mpre", "21Mpre", "21Mpre", "21Mpre", "24Mpre", "24Mpre", "24Mpre", 
    "24Mpre", "24Mpre", "24Mpre", "27Mpre", "27Mpre", "27Mpre", "27Mpre", 
    "27Mpre", "27Mpre", "27Mpre", "30Mpre", "30Mpre", "30Mpre", "30Mpre", 
    "30Mpre", "33Mpre", "33Mpre", "33Mpre", "33Mpre", "33Mpre", "33Mpre", 
    "33Mpre", "36Mpre", "36Mpre", "36Mpre", "36Mpre", "36Mpre", "36Mpre", 
    "3M", "3M", "3M", "3M", "3M", "3M", "3MPre", "3MPre", "3MPre", 
    "3MPre", "3MPre", "3MPre", "3MPre", "6M", "6M", "6M", "6M", "6M", 
    "6M", "6M", "6Mpre", "6Mpre", "6Mpre", "6Mpre", "6Mpre", "9M", 
    "9M", "9M", "9M", "9M", "9Mpre", "9Mpre", "9Mpre", "9Mpre", "9Mpre", 
    "9Mpre", "9Mpre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre"), 
perc = c(48.4375, 48.4375, 48.4375, 48.4375, 48.4375, 48.4375, 
81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 79.5918367346939, 
79.5918367346939, 79.5918367346939, 79.5918367346939, 79.5918367346939, 
79.5918367346939, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 51.7241379310345, 
51.7241379310345, 51.7241379310345, 51.7241379310345, 51.7241379310345, 
85.7142857142857, 85.7142857142857, 85.7142857142857, 85.7142857142857, 
85.7142857142857, 85.7142857142857, 78.9473684210526, 78.9473684210526, 
78.9473684210526, 78.9473684210526, 78.9473684210526, 78.9473684210526, 
78.9473684210526, 79.2452830188679, 79.2452830188679, 79.2452830188679, 
79.2452830188679, 79.2452830188679, 77.5862068965517, 77.5862068965517, 
77.5862068965517, 77.5862068965517, 77.5862068965517, 77.5862068965517, 
77.5862068965517, 81.4814814814815, 81.4814814814815, 81.4814814814815, 
81.4814814814815, 81.4814814814815, 81.4814814814815, 56.140350877193, 
56.140350877193, 56.140350877193, 56.140350877193, 56.140350877193, 
56.140350877193, 78.9473684210526, 78.9473684210526, 78.9473684210526, 
78.9473684210526, 78.9473684210526, 78.9473684210526, 78.9473684210526, 
69.6428571428571, 69.6428571428571, 69.6428571428571, 69.6428571428571, 
69.6428571428571, 69.6428571428571, 69.6428571428571, 70.5882352941177, 
70.5882352941177, 70.5882352941177, 70.5882352941177, 70.5882352941177, 
57.3770491803279, 57.3770491803279, 57.3770491803279, 57.3770491803279, 
57.3770491803279, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 
76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 
73.9130434782609, 73.9130434782609, 73.9130434782609, 73.9130434782609, 
73.9130434782609, 73.9130434782609), Gender = c("Achromobacter", 
"Burkholderia", "Minority microorganisms", "Pseudomonas", 
"SAMS", "SARM", "Achromobacter", "Aspergillus", "Minority microorganisms", 
"Pseudomonas", "SAMS", "SARM", "Achromobacter", "Aspergillus", 
"Burkholderia", "Minority microorganisms", "Pseudomonas", 
"SARM", "Achromobacter", "Aspergillus", "Burkholderia", "Minority microorganisms", 
"Pseudomonas", "SAMS", "SARM", "Aspergillus", "Minority microorganisms", 
"Pseudomonas", "SAMS", "SARM", "Achromobacter", "Aspergillus", 
"Burkholderia", "Minority microorganisms", "Pseudomonas", 
"SARM", "Achromobacter", "Aspergillus", "Burkholderia", "Minority microorganisms", 
"Pseudomonas", "SAMS", "SARM", "Aspergillus", "Burkholderia", 
"Pseudomonas", "SAMS", "SARM", "Achromobacter", "Aspergillus", 
"Burkholderia", "Minority microorganisms", "Pseudomonas", 
"SAMS", "SARM", "Aspergillus", "Burkholderia", "Minority microorganisms", 
"Pseudomonas", "SAMS", "SARM", "Burkholderia", "Minority microorganisms", 
"Pseudomonas", "SAMS", "SARM", "Stenotrophomonas", "Achromobacter", 
"Aspergillus", "Burkholderia", "Minority microorganisms", 
"Pseudomonas", "SAMS", "SARM", "Achromobacter", "Burkholderia", 
"Minority microorganisms", "Pseudomonas", "SAMS", "SARM", 
"Stenotrophomonas", "Burkholderia", "Minority microorganisms", 
"Pseudomonas", "SAMS", "SARM", "Achromobacter", "Burkholderia", 
"Pseudomonas", "SAMS", "SARM", "Achromobacter", "Aspergillus", 
"Minority microorganisms", "Pseudomonas", "SAMS", "SARM", 
"Stenotrophomonas", "Achromobacter", "Burkholderia", "Minority microorganisms", 
"Pseudomonas", "SAMS", "SARM"), perc_presencia = c(4.8, 9.5, 
9.5, 19, 19, 38.1, 5, 5, 10, 25, 20, 35, 7.4, 14.8, 7.4, 
3.7, 33.3, 33.3, 7.7, 15.4, 7.7, 7.7, 26.9, 11.5, 23.1, 12.5, 
25, 25, 12.5, 25, 4.8, 14.3, 4.8, 4.8, 52.4, 19, 6.5, 12.9, 
12.9, 3.2, 32.3, 9.7, 22.6, 11.1, 11.1, 50, 11.1, 16.7, 3.6, 
10.7, 14.3, 3.6, 42.9, 10.7, 14.3, 6.9, 17.2, 6.9, 41.4, 
10.3, 17.2, 4.5, 9.1, 27.3, 36.4, 18.2, 4.5, 6.2, 6.2, 12.5, 
6.2, 25, 6.2, 37.5, 4.3, 4.3, 13, 17.4, 43.5, 13, 4.3, 13, 
4.3, 39.1, 13, 30.4, 4.3, 8.7, 21.7, 30.4, 34.8, 4, 8, 12, 
28, 12, 32, 4, 11.5, 11.5, 3.8, 30.8, 34.6, 7.7)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -104L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

y posteriormente he utilizado el siguiente código:

```
Evolucion_ais.ggplot %>% select(tiempos,
                        Gender,
                        perc_presencia,
                         perc) %>% 
pivot_wider(names_from = "Gender",values_from = perc_presencia)->my_df;my_df





   ggplot(my_df, aes(x = tiempos, y = perc, group=1))+
geom_line(linewidth = 1)+
geom_pie_glyph(colour = 'black',
               slices = c('Achromobacter','Burkholderia','Minority microorganisms', 'Pseudomonas','Stenotrophomonas',
                          'SAMS','SARM','Aspergillus'),radius =1.35)+
geom_label(data= Evolucion_ais.ggplot, aes(x = tiempos,y = perc_presencia, fill=Gender,
                                     label = paste(sprintf("%0.1f", round(perc_presencia, digits = 1)),"%"), 
                                     nudge_x = 0.3,
                                     direction = "Total",
                                     vjust = -1.0)) +
theme_minimal() +
theme(
  legend.position = "top",
  legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
  legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
  legend.title.align = 0,
  strip.background = element_blank(),
  strip.text = element_blank(),
  axis.title.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(1, 0, 0, 0), "mm"), size = 1),
  axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 1, 0, 0), "mm"), size = 1),
  panel.spacing.x = unit(4, "mm")
) +
labs(fill = NULL)+

scale_y_continuous(
  labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%"),
  limits = c(0, 100),
  breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 5)
) +
# scale_fill_manual(values = c("#8A2BE2","#5F9EA0","cyan","#A897A9",          "#8B4513","#FFA500","#E1B378","#32CD32"),
#                   labels = etiqs) +
geom_vline(xintercept = 13, colour="blue", linetype = "longdash",size=2.5) +
geom_vline(xintercept = 5, colour="red", linetype = "longdash",size=2.5)
```

obteniendo esta gráfica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me gustaría que las etiquetas se dispusieran cerca o en el sector del gráfico donde corresponde pero no logro cambiarlo
¿Qué debería modificar?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Adrian, fijte si podes modificar el ejemplo, por que no es reproducible. Pega a tu pregunta la salida de esto: `dput(BD_Micro_grap2)`

Comment: Gracias @PatricioMoracho, ya he actualizado el post añadiendo la bd a tratar con dput. Por unos días di de baja la pregunta ya que no tuve mucho tiempo para actualizarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colocar una etiqueta en cada sector de cada "torta" no es posible (al menos con un esfuerzo razonable), para poder hacerlo hay que saber la posición de cada porción, y esto solo se conoce dentro del ámbito de `geom_pie_glyph()`, que vale decir, no implementa ninguna funcionalidad al respecto, en mi opinión, por que hacerlo conspira contra la "legibilidad" del gráfico. Por lo que a menos que reescribamos `geom_pie_glyph()`, la única alternativa es acercar las etiquetas al centro de cada "torta", el cual es el punto determinado por `Gender` y `Perc`, se puede lograr con un `geom_label()` estándar, pero deberías generar un nuevo `data.frame` ajustando los datos para ir variando el centro, así cada etiqueta no queda solapada:

```
Evolucion_ais.ggplot %>%
  arrange(tiempos, -perc_presencia) %>% 
  group_by(tiempos) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  select(tiempos, Gender, perc, perc_presencia, id) -> df_labels
```

Luego habría que incorporar este `label` a tu gráfica

```
  geom_label(data = df_labels,
             mapping = aes(x = tiempos, 
                           y = perc + (id * 3),
                           fill = Gender,
                           label = paste(sprintf("%0.1f", 
                                                 round(perc_presencia, digits = 1)),"%")),
             nudge_x = 0.5,
             nudge_y = -3
             )
```

Aunque esta opción, logra el objetivo de que las etiquetas se acerquen al centro de cada "torta" me resulta un poco mejor el uso de `geom_label_repel()` que se toma el trabajo de ubicar las etiquetas sin solapamiento y a partir de los datos originales. Además, ofrece una gran variedad de [configuraciones](https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples). **Importante**: si vas a usar esta opción, asegurate de tener la última versión de `ggplot` instalada.

El ejemplo sería algo así:

```
library(PieGlyph)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(my_df, aes(x = tiempos, y = perc, group=1)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 13, colour="blue", linetype = "longdash",size=2.5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 5, colour="red", linetype = "longdash",size=2.5) +
  geom_pie_glyph(colour = 'black',
                 slices = c('Achromobacter','Burkholderia','Minority microorganisms', 
                            'Pseudomonas','Stenotrophomonas',
                            'SAMS','SARM','Aspergillus'), 
                 radius = 1.35) +
  geom_label_repel(data = Evolucion_ais.ggplot,
            aes(x=tiempos, 
                y = perc , 
                label = paste(sprintf("%0.1f", round(perc_presencia, digits = 1)),"%"),
                fill = Gender,
                #color = Gender
            ),
            label.size        = .5,
            max.overlaps      = Inf,
            size              = 4,
            show.legend       = FALSE,
            force             = 0.5,
            nudge_x           = .8,
            direction         = "y",
            hjust             = 0,
            segment.size      = 0.5,
            segment.curvature = -0.1,
            segment.square    = FALSE,
            segment.inflect   = FALSE,
            segment.linetype  = 2
            ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.title.align = 0,
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(1, 0, 0, 0), "mm"), size = 1),
    axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 1, 0, 0), "mm"), size = 1),
    panel.spacing.x = unit(4, "mm")
  ) +
  labs(fill = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(40, 100),
    breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 5)
  ) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice algunos cambios con respecto a tu gráfico

- Para maximizar el área de las tortas, ajuste `scale_y_continuous` y `limits`
- Con el mismo objetivo anterior: `guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))` pra que las leyendas queden en una sola línea
- También cambie el orden de los `geom` para que favorecer la legibilidad de estos

A mod de comparación, este sería el resultado con el `geom_label()` estándar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias Patricio